# On MySQL import: ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\''

Tags: database, mysql

I'm receiving the following error while trying to import my DB:

ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\''.

I've done some searching and found that this can be because the dump was not created with the --hex-blob command.

Unfortunately, I don't have the opportunity to do that now as this was the last backup made prior to my host having an untimely raid/hardware failure.

Is there anything I can do to get my DB imported?

Update:

Tried using --force and --max_allowed_packet=1000M when importing. Here's a sample of what it returned...

```
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 32769: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '}',1,1352344791,0),('performanceCache','',0,1317594187,0),('promenu','a:1:{s:7:\' at line 1
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 32769: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a:7:{i:9' at line 1
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 32769: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a:19:{s:10:\"promenu_id\"' at line 1
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 32769: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's:1:\"9\"' at line 1
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 32769: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's:13:\"promenu_title\"' at line 1
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 32769: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check th                                                                                                             line 1
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 32769: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check th                                                                                                             iption\"' at line 1
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 32769: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check th
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 32769: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check th                                                                                                             ' at line 1
ERROR at line 32769: Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 32769: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check th
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cache_store` ENABLE KEYS */' at line 1
ERROR at line 682781: Unknown command '\''.
ERROR at line 682781: Unknown command '\''.
ERROR at line 682781: Unknown command '\''.
ERROR at line 682781: Unknown command '\''.
ERROR 1153 (08S01) at line 682781: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet'
```

Comment: Look at line 32769 in the file you're trying to import.

Comment: I've tried the following:

`awk '{ if (NR==1153) print $0 }' database.sql >> line1153.sql`

per what I found on [this similar stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888589/mysql-error-at-line-1153-unknown-command) and it comes back empty. When I try `vim +32769 filename` it takes me to line 285.

Comment: 32768 is 2^15, or the maximum signed 16 bit integer. Surely the line number being 1 more than this is more than a coincidence.

Comment: You have binary blobs in your DB, try adding --hex-blob to your mysqldump statement.

Comment: Rajshri: As I mentioned this is what I suspected and the source no longer exists so --hex-blob isn't an option. This is the last dump I have. Can I convert the blobs to hex before importing?

Answer (score 3):

Tried MySQLWorkbench and realized I forgot to add `--default-character-set=utf8` during command line.  Tried it again with `--default-character-set=utf8` and now import works from command line too.

The command line I have is:

```
mysql -u <username> -pac1 <password> --default-character-set=utf8 <schema> < <dumpfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

DB ended up being corrupted. Was unable to recover or import.

Comment: I think I'm also facing the same problem. When I view the .sql file it shows some weird correctors not sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

You will get that error if it's not an `SQL` file you are trying to import. I once tried to import a `tar.gz` (it had a different name and I forgot it was compressed and actually a collection of SQL files) and this error reminded me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, try importing with MySQLWorkbench instead of the command line,
this worked for me.