# Mysql restore issue

Tags: mysql, restore

I used to have mysql 5.6 server. I backed up with like this command.

```
mysqldump -u Myuser -pMypasswor Mydatabase > C:\backups\Mydatabase.sql
```

I removed Mysql 5.6 and installed 5.5 version.

Now I try to restore my database but it fails. Firstly I tried this

```
mysqldump -u Myuser -pMypasswor Mydatabase < C:\backups\Mydatabase.sql
```

Afterwards on Cmd Connected with

```
mysql -u Myuser -pMypassword

Mydatabase < C:\backups\Mydatabase.sql
```

I got this error

> ERROR:
>   Unknown command '\a'.
>
> ERROR:
>   Unknown command '\m'.
>
> ERROR:
>   Unknown command '\I'.
>     -> ;

I googled but I cant solve my own
Any idea is appreciated

Comment: Try adding quotation marks: "C:\backups\Mydatabase.sql"

Comment: @Bilzard it didnt work

Comment: This is an issue with your data or the way you exported it, and there can be several reasons. I would advice you to try everything [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888589/mysql-error-at-line-1153-unknown-command) and you will probably find the answer